Expo Router Crushing the app when navigating on iOS
I am trying to navigate to the profile from the verify screen upon complete authentication using the following code:
const verify = async ()=>{
  .....
  if (completeSignUp.status === "complete") {
        await setActive({ session: completeSignUp.createdSessionId });
        setState((s) => ({ ...s, loading: false, error_msg: "", code: "" }));
        router.replace("/profile"); // <---- This line
      } else {
        setState((s) => ({
          ...s,
          loading: false,
          error_msg: "Failed to verify your email.",
          code: "",
        }));
      }

}

Now when i call router.replace('/profile') the Expo-Go just closes itself on ios but on android everything is smooth. What might the issue. Here is my route structure:
app
   - _layout.tsx
   - verify.tsx
   - profile.tsx


Versions:
"expo-router": "~3.5.20",
"expo": "~51.0.24",


Try use router.push("profile")
